# Webview loads the same url everytime the activity comes to focus

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a `Webview` in my app. When I open my app and switch to another app or just go to the homescreen, and then re-open my app. The `Webview` loads the url I have set for it to load in the `onCreate()` method, and not the url I was visiting before I switched out the app.

I am saving the url with the help of the sharedprefrences using this method: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

The standard savedUrl is the standard Url it loads in the first `onCreate()` method, but is it so that the values I am writing to there are also reset when the app is paused?

Some log:

```
02-05 09:46:57.443 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/SAVING_URL: http://www.remotepressure.com/
02-05 09:46:57.453 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source:  (1)
02-05 09:46:57.453 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source:  (1)
02-05 09:46:57.453 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null", source:  (1)
02-05 09:47:00.201 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:571] focusedNodeChanged
02-05 09:47:00.214 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:213] updateKeyboardVisibility: type [0], flags [0], show [true]
02-05 09:47:00.214 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/cr_Ime: [AdapterInputConnection.java:178] updateState [] [0 0] [-1 -1] [true]
02-05 09:47:00.465 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:571] focusedNodeChanged
02-05 09:47:00.489 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 W/cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a connection for the pid: 24132
02-05 09:47:00.878 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/SAVING_URL: http://www.remotepressure.com/welcome-page
02-05 09:47:00.888 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source:  (1)
02-05 09:47:00.888 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null", source:  (1)
02-05 09:47:00.888 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null", source:  (1)
02-05 09:47:06.488 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/APP: PAUSE
02-05 09:47:06.638 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/cr_Ime: [AdapterInputConnection.java:499] finishComposingText
02-05 09:47:06.735 24132-24138/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 W/art: Suspending all threads took: 19.298ms
02-05 09:47:06.735 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/cr_Ime: [AdapterInputConnection.java:499] finishComposingText
02-05 09:47:09.386 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:27] Constructor
02-05 09:47:09.387 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:241] attach
02-05 09:47:09.387 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 W/art: Attempt to remove non-JNI local reference, dumping thread
02-05 09:47:09.388 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 W/AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached. Ignoring
02-05 09:47:09.389 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/cr_Ime: [InputMethodManagerWrapper.java:56] isActive: false
02-05 09:47:09.389 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/APP: CREATE
02-05 09:47:09.392 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/LOADING_URL: http://www.remotepressure.com
02-05 09:47:09.400 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/cr_Ime: [ImeAdapter.java:241] attach
02-05 09:47:09.404 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/APP: START
02-05 09:47:09.405 24132-24132/com.example.okke.testwebapp02 D/APP: RESUME`
```

Saving the URL:

```
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if (fromLogin) {
                //String javascript = "javascript:(function(){ document.getElementById('mib').value = 'aaa'; })()";
                //String javascript = "javascript:document.forms[0].username.value = '"+test01+"';";

                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var x = document.getElementById('modlgn-username').value = '" + userName + "';");
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:var z = document.getElementById('modlgn-passwd').value = '" + passWord + "';");
            /*mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
                    "l=document.getElementById('form-login-submit');"+
                    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
                    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
                    "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
                    "})()");*/
                //var y = $document.getElementById('form-login-submit').click();");
                //mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript: var y = document.getElementById('form-login-submit'); y.click();");
            }
            if (mWebView.getUrl() != null) {
                SharedPreferences sharedpref = Web.this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpref.edit();
                String temp = mWebView.getUrl();
                Log.d("SAVING_URL", temp);
                editor.putString(getString(R.string.loaded_url), mWebView.getUrl());
                editor.commit();
            }
```

Loading the URL in `onCreate()`

```
Log.d("LOADING_URL", getResources().getString(R.string.loaded_url));
mWebView.loadUrl(getResources().getString((R.string.loaded_url)));
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: Could you control commit result? Simply, boolean isCommited = editor.commit()

Comment: Maybe one more than mistake in this case. First you have javascript error about change document state, second you always call static url when application open(getResource.getString(id)).

Comment: Yeah but doesn't that url change when I update it with the editor?

Comment: did you fight this ? I'm fighting with same problem, i'm passing good url but still webview is using the old one. Like it will reload page with old url, clear cache etc doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you use `editor.getString(R.string.loaded_url, "")` if you are using shared preference rather than just `getResources().getString((R.string.loaded_url))`?

**EDIT**
not `editor.getString(R.string.loaded_url, "")`
but
`sharedpref.getString(R.string.loaded_url, "")`
my bad

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean `sharedPreference.getString()`

Comment: the `getString()` method requires an `String` and not an `int` like R.string.loaded_url.

Comment: use it like this `sharedpref.getString(getString(R.string.loaded_url), "")`. But just my suggestion is use a new string varialble. something like `editor.putString("loaded_url", mWebView.getUrl())` and get it using `sharedpref.getString("loaded_url", "")`